# Is there any difference between headers being stored as an object or as new Headers(...)?

Tags: javascript, fetch, http-headers

I am refactoring some code and have come across multiple fetch calls, some of which implement headers in a plain object format, and others use the built in `new Headers({ /* header object */})` format.

```
const headers = {
    Authorisation: 'Bearer some token data',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

console.log(new Headers(headers));

/* OUTPUT OF CONSOLE LOG
headers: HeadersList {
    [Symbol(headers map)]: [Map],
    [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: null
}
*/
```

Is there any appreciable difference to a `fetch` call between passing headers as `new Headers(...)` vs just a regular object?

Comment: Isn't it the American English form with a "z" for the [Authorization header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization)?

Comment: A [`Headers` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers) can handle multiple values for the same key, which a vanilla object won't.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl you are correct. My Britishness made me spell it correctly subliminally!

Comment: @jonrsharpe cheers for the succinct explanation. I'm not sending in anything crazy, just some strings so I think I'll be happy with a plain object since 4/5 of them already use this.